# Python ssh with tunnel in subprocess

Tags: python, mysql, ssh

I'm write some python script and I want to tunnel my MySQL Server through a SSH Connection and perform some SQL requests.

```
import MySQLdb  
import os

handle = os.popen('ssh config -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306')
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",
                     user="Username",
                     passwd="Secret",
                     db="dbName")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tablename")
for row in cur.fetchall():
      print row[1]
db.close()
handle.close()
```

The connection is working fine but it does not close the script (subprocess) after the execution, furthermore it's adding some white spaces in front of every printed row.

Thanks for reading and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but, [`os.popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen) is super-obsolete. Use the `subprocess` module instead.

> Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete. Use the subprocess module. Check especially the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section.

With `subprocess` you'll be able to kill the process (you cannot do that easily with `os.popen` since `close` only closes the handle)

```
handle = subprocess.Popen('ssh config -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306'.split())
...
handle.kill()
```

note the `split` part to pass a list of args instead of a string. That's quick & dirty but some OSes don't support passing a string to `Popen`. The proper way is: `["ssh","config","-L","3306:127.0.0.1:3306"]` so you can pass args with spaces in it transparently.

Comment: thank you, i ve changed it to the proper way, it's still not working correctly. now it connects to the Database sever and executes the commands on the DatabaseServer but i need it to run the sql requests local, the ssh connection should be only open in background.

Comment: but `subprocess` does that: it runs the process in the background.

Comment: oh I don't get it. It always shows the username of the database server when it executes the database query.

Comment: I found the problem, i am using sleep inside the main process this is causing the problem... hopefully i will find some new way to make the script idle (i am not waiting for any input just to slow down the script)